# Can you break someone's attention on something?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

You can write something like:

> Mary's focus was broken by the boys sitting behind her.

However, can you write something like this?

> Mary's focus on biology was broken by the boys sitting behind her.

Or

> Mary's focus on her biology assignment was broken by the boys sitting behind her.

I think I've never seen the structure of the two last examples, so I'm not sure.

If they are incorrect, what's the closest correct alternative?

Comment: I wonder if you try to find examples of how a word is collocated with another before asking these types of questions. You could do this by looking for: to break focus or broken focus or focus was broken. I doubt you will find any hits from good sites with that collocation. You might try "interrupt".

Comment: Your third example is fine and will be generally understood, but it begs the question "The boys' what?" Their behavior, their mere presence, laughing, talking? In other words, are you talking about Mary's hormones or something the boys are doing that breaks her focus?

Comment: @MarkHubbard All of the examples call for focus being broken. Would you say: My focus was broken by x?

Comment: @Lambie - Probably not, but I have no problem with _x broke my focus_.

Comment: @J.R. Same difference. And here it is passive.

Comment: The answer really depends on whether you want to express this as the average guy on the street would say it.  If so, the sentence would probably not begin with "Mary's focus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an editor, my recommendation is: **interrupted or disturbed my focus**.

I will spare the google hits, but they are there in great numbers.

There are 412 hits for break [my] focus. I do not recommend that usage.

**break is often used with attention**: **My attention was broken** by a knock on the door.

Answer (score 1):

**concentration** is more often **broken** than **attention** is.  Attention is usually **distracted**.   If you're using **focus** as a synonym for **concentration**, **broken** would work, I suppose, but "to break someone's focus" seems off to me.